# moderation analysis in SAS

Tags: sas, modifier

I want to understand whether a third variable moderated the intervention on outcomes. In this case, I have Bright as the intervention treatment status (0/1), CIB_MSR_ad2_un as the outcome of interest (continuous), and PIT0HighAll as the moderator (0/1). When I ran the codes below, I kept getting weird results. Is it because the sample size was too small? Did I do the correct coding here? Thanks

```
proc anova data=analysiswithout18; 
class Bright; 
model CIB_MSR_ad2_un=Bright; 
means Bright; 
by PIT0HighAll; 
run;
```

[image]

[image]